# how to take the value form edittext in a listview?

Tags: android

I have a custom list with one textView and one 
    edit text in each row. My question is: whenever user enters 
    any number inside the edittext,at that time i want to take the 
    value from the edittext and add it with the previous value and
     displayed in the top textview.
        For eg. Say inside number of edittext i entered 10 in any 
    edittext. 10is the first number entered.then it is going to add
     with 0.after that if he enter 15 in another edittext,then 10+15 = **25**
     should be displayed in the top textview.

Comment: You can get the text stored in an `EditText` using: `editText.getText().toString()`.

Comment: i can take the value from the edittext when the button is pressed.but can you tell me how can i get it exactly at that time,when  the value is entered??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it...

That was as simple as using setOnFocusListener. If the focus gets lost from the edit text.at that the boolean hasFocus parameter gets **false**. and we can easily collect the value inside the edit text. But thanks for you support guys. Thanks 1ce again.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  String content = edtEditText.getText().toString();
  tvTextView.setText(content);
```

Comment: i can take the value from the edittext when the button is pressed.but can you tell me how can i get it exactly at that time,when  the value is entered??

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure,this would help...but you can try with this:

Get a setOnFocusListener on your edit text like:

```
mEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {
         int s=Integer.parseInt(mEditText.getText().toString());
         int ps=Integer.parseInt(mTextView.getText().toString());
         mTextView.setText((s+ps)+"");
         mEditText.setText("");// clear editText after adding its value to textview
    }
});
```

don't forget to empty the edittext when focus is gone,otherwise when user would click onto edittext even to delete previous one,value would again be added to your textview.

Answer (score 1):

You have to Use A TextWatcher on the EditText View like this for That:

```
EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.e1);

TextWatcher checker = new TextWatcher() { 
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (ChecknotNull()) {
            TextView1.setText(edittext1.getText().toString().trim());;
   Note: You can Also Go on Concating the values with the  
         previous values Of the TextView(InShort,Perform Logic Here)
       }
    }

    private boolean ChecknotNull() {
        return editText1.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0;
    }
};  

//Set the checker method for the EditText View like this Way
editText1.addTextChangedListener(checker);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Adapter, do this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    p = values.get(position);
    if (vi == null) {

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_items, null);
            holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            holder.editText = (EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.et);

            holder.editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                                i++;
                                int n = Integer.parseInt(holder.text.getText().toString());
                                int m = Integer.parseInt(s.getText().toString());
                                holder.text.setText("" + n + m);
                                }
                                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
                                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
                    }); 

            vi.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }
    return vi;
    }
```